# Align two div's to left

Tags: html, css, web

Basically what i want to do is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wQBq5/20/

without using tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/vaDCQ/

Comment: The margin-left is cheating :P, if you change the content of the first div it overlay the content of the next div

Comment: Yes I agree, I don't know how to do it another way.

Comment: It's not what I'd call cheating, it's the reality of working with floated divs.  And if you change the content of a table cell, then you can also stretch it out of its boundaries as well, such as a big image.

Answer (score 2):

This fiddle shows the basics:  http://jsfiddle.net/cA3su/.  But there are differences.  For one thing, the "inner" divs don't stretch all the way to the right like the table does.  For another, you need to understand how floats and clears work.  It takes some practice and experimentation.  In short, divs will never work exactly the way tables do.  But once you know how to do it, divs get you free of a lot of the headaches that tables create.

Comment: For example, if i insert an image with 100% of width inside of the right div, it will not go under the left div?

Comment: Yes that's one of the things that can happen, if elements are too wide, then they don't get floated properly.  It's up to you to take care of the widths, as the other examples showed.  I wanted to keep my example simple, but stress that you really need to learn about floats and CSS layouts to use them...there are "gotchas" to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using float.

You can use something like this (basic example):

html:

```
<div class="left-container">1</div>
<div class="right-container">
  <div class="number2">2</div>
  <div class="number3">3</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.left-container{float:left;width:100px;}
.right-container{float:left;width:100px;}
.right-container .number2{float:left;width:100%;}
.right-container .number3{float:left;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my example.. http://jsfiddle.net/wQBq5/37/